# DataGridView showing an empty row when no datasets are available

Tags: c#, datagridview

My `DataGridView` is always showing one empty row when no datasets are available. Data is coming from an Entity Framework 6 database through a binding source. My expectation would be that when no data set is available, the `DataGridView` just shows the row headers, but nothing else.

[image: dgv showing empty row]

From `InitializeCompnent()`:

```
    this.dgvWarnings.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
    this.dgvWarnings.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
    this.dgvWarnings.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
    this.dgvWarnings.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 384);
    this.dgvWarnings.MultiSelect = false;
    this.dgvWarnings.Name = "dgvWarnings";
    this.dgvWarnings.ReadOnly = true;
    this.dgvWarnings.SelectionMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewSelectionMode.CellSelect;
    this.dgvWarnings.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(817, 95);
    this.dgvWarnings.TabIndex = 115;
    this.dgvWarnings.DoubleClick += new System.EventHandler(this.dgvWarnings_DoubleClick);
```

From main class:

```
    private void Startseite_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _context = new SqlContext();

        _context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        _context.ProgramWarnings.Load();
        bindProgramWarningList.DataSource = _context.ProgramWarnings.Local.ToBindingList().Where(t => t.Acknowledged == false);

        dgvWarnings.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        dgvWarnings.AutoSize = true;

        dgvWarnings.DataSource = bindProgramWarningList;

        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn column = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        column.DataPropertyName = "WarningMessage";
        column.Name = "Warnung";
        dgvWarnings.Columns.Add(column);

        column = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        column.DataPropertyName = "WarningTime";
        column.Name = "Datum/Uhrzeit";
        dgvWarnings.Columns.Add(column);
```

Some Event:

```
private void dgvWarnings_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dgvWarnings.SelectedRows.Count == 1)
        {

            ((ProgramWarning)dgvWarnings.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem).Acknowledged = true;
            _context.SaveChanges();
            bindProgramWarningList.DataSource = _context.ProgramWarnings.Local.ToBindingList().Where(t => t.Acknowledged == false);
            bindProgramWarningList.ResetBindings(true);


        }
    }
```

Comment: You must have [`AllowUserToAddRows` enabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.allowusertoaddrows?view=netcore-3.1). As far as I know, if users can add rows then there will always be a blank row visible.

Comment: No rows shall be created from the dgv. It is supposed to just display the result from the database. If no result, no rows should show up (especially no empty row).

Comment: Then set it to false.

Comment: It is set to false (see first line of source code above)...

Comment: I can't recreate your problem. If you debug at runtime do you see it change back to true? Have you tried deleting the grid and starting with a fresh one? That fixed another bizarre problem here on SO recently.

Comment: Thanks, I did some further debugging based on your hint that this is no normal behaviour. It seems that this line is causing the trouble:
bindProgramWarningList.DataSource = _context.ProgramWarnings.Local.ToBindingList().Where(t => t.Acknowledged == false);
I think the intended filtering needs to be done in another way...

Comment: Also try setting `AllowNew` on BindingList to false, that might be overriding the grid property.

Comment: The way of filtering the binding list just seems to be not supported. When I remove the "where"-filter, everything works fine.

Comment: You should filter before calling ToBindingList() anyway.

Comment: Yes, I would agree. But if I filter before calling ToBindingList(), ToBindingList will not show up as an option anymore. I can only do ToList() afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

try to move the following instructions after you have initialized the grid columns:

```
    _context = new SqlContext();

    _context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    _context.ProgramWarnings.Load();
    bindProgramWarningList.DataSource = 
    _context.ProgramWarnings.Local.ToBindingList().Where(t => t.Acknowledged == false);
```

Also verify that your grid starts empty after being initialized completely and whether it is this command that adds your ghost line (just remark bindProgramWarningList.DataSource =...)

Cheers

ps: It seems you edited while I was posting. If it is the datasource, try loading the result on a new list and use that as datasource.
In worst case scenario you could even check if there is an empty line and remove it on your View list...

Comment: Whatever where-clause I use in the example, I always get one empty dataset back, if the database is empty. My assumption is that binding list simply doesn't support what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: If you bind an empty list is it fine? Have you tried it?
If so do the following:

List<yourtype> ViewList = _context.ProgramWarnings.Local.ToBindingList().Where(t => t.Acknowledged == false);

If the viewlist it is not empy and has 1 entry, you could verify that the list item is empty by checking the values and removing it, and finally bind that to the grid:
bindProgramWarningList.DataSource = ViewList ;